# Changing style after n no. of results- PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Hi i use PHP to fetch data from database using while loop. A class paid or unpaid is applied through database field value. Paid members are shown 2 members per line and unpaid 3 per line and that are working well for me. But a small little issue is when paid members are ended, i want a line-break then display unpaid members from a new line 3 in a row. How i can do that ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="main paid">
  ABC
</div>
<div class="main paid">
  ABC
</div>
<div class="main paid">
  ABC
</div>
<div class="main unpaid">
  ABC
</div>
<div class="main unpaid">
  ABC
</div>
<div class="main unpaid">
  ABC
</div>
<div class="main unpaid">
  ABC
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main{
  float:left;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}
.paid{
  width:49%;
}
.unpaid{
  width:32%;
}
```

Working Fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/qzxyyo2x/1/**

Here paid or unpaid are table values fetched from database. Width is applied to them. I want to add a "line-break" when paid members are ended to display unpaid members 3 in a row from the next row. In this question i need a line-break after 3 results. and if paid members are 2,4,5,6 or whatever. I need a line-break after displaying all paid members.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: How i can do it with CSS ???

Comment: AND i use a while loop in PHP that repeats again n again until data is in table. It fetches paid or unpaid i.e. class name from table and in div it displays value i.e. ABC or any value.,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some clearfix code to trigger unpaid classes to break with `clear: both;` however if applied to the entire `.unpaid` class, all unpaid classes would be on their own line.

Incorrect Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qzxyyo2x/2/

A quick solution would be a new class called `.clearfix`. You could use this whenever an `unpaid` class follows a `paid` class, but not when an `unpaid` class follows an `unpaid` class. This logic will have to be done in PHP.

Correct Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qzxyyo2x/3/

An even more elegant solution would involve creating extra `div`s surrounding each of your rows, but this may involve changing more of your logic than just one class.

Comment: Hi i don't know the no of paid divs. Value paid or unpaid is being fetched from database. So both solutions are not enough...

Comment: Okay, you can do this with just CSS then. `.paid+.unpaid { clear: both; }` https://jsfiddle.net/qzxyyo2x/5/

Comment: Fantastic. Glad to hear! In the long run I do think it's worth investing in modifying the div layout as a whole, but I'm glad this quick hack works for you.